# Extract word before all matching character in bash

Tags: bash, shell

How to extract all the string before `:`, I could get only the first as below

```
$ echo "cc_dd:qqq www;aa_bb:ll fi;ee_ff:bb dd ee" | sed 's/:.*//g'
$ cc_dd
# want to print cc_dd aa_bb and ee_ff
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? reason would help my with next posts, thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I think in its current form, the question is a bit misleading. The string before the last : is not just "ee_ff". It is the whole string up to the last : . You need to specify how many characters you need to be extracted or you need to specify another character(;) to act as the start of the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short ***grep*** approach:

```
s="cc_dd:qqq www;aa_bb:ll fi;ee_ff:bb dd ee"
grep -Po '[^;:]+(?=:)' <<< $s
```

`-P` option, allows Perl regular expressions

`-o` option, tells to print only matched substrings

`(?=:)` - positive lookahead assertion, assures that desired substring is followed by `:`

The output:

```
cc_dd
aa_bb
ee_ff
```

---

*Performance comparison:*

```
time (for i in {1..1000}; do grep -Po '[^;:]+(?=:)' <<< $s > /dev/null; done;)

real    0m1.936s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.236s
```

---

```
time (for i in {1..1000}; do awk -v RS=\; '{split($0,a,":"); print a[1]}' <<< $s > /dev/null; done;)

real    0m2.633s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.264s
```

Comment: what if I have more that 3? printing as $1,$3 and $5 won't work all the time, its a variable

Comment: @Krish, you should mention it in your question

Comment: got you, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
echo "cc_dd:qqq www;aa_bb:ll fi;ee_ff:bb dd ee" | 
awk -v RS=\; '{split($0,a,":"); print a[1]}'

cc_dd
aa_bb
ee_ff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[;:]' '{print $1,$3,$5}' OFS='\n' file

cc_dd
aa_bb
ee_ff
```